# Obtaining the Maximum Field Size of an Access Column

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Hi all you Stack Overflowers. I am having bit of a dilemma here. I need to obtain the Maximum of characters you may enter into a field but I have had no success and Google did not produce anyhing similar to what I need

Here is my Code

```
            lvwDestination.Columns.Add("Fields in Database", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            lvwDestination.Columns.Add("DataType", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            lvwDestination.Columns.Add("Max", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            for (int i = 0; i < DataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {

                _lvwItem = new ListViewItem(DataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, 0);

                _lvwItem.Name = DataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;

                _lvwItem.SubItems.Add(DataTable.Columns[i].DataType.Name.ToString());

               _lvwItem.SubItems.Add(DataTable.Columns[i].MaxLength.ToString());
                lvwDestination.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { _lvwItem });


            }
```

Now as you can see I have tried

```
_lvwItem.SubItems.Add(DataTable.Columns[i].MaxLength.ToString());
```

but the only thing that this came up with is -1 for every column. I have also made sure that my columns do in fact have the property field size attribute on. The .ColumnName and .DataType works perfectly but .MaxLength produces -1 always.
Thanks in advance for anyone that might be able to come up with a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/958101/754438

Comment: Actually no not a duplicate as you can see that question populates from XML I populate from Access so no my question is not a duplicate. Also that question does not state a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

try setting following property: `OledbDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey`  of your `DataAdapter` before calling the `Fill` method...

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try it out now and come back to you

Comment: That is not working it returns 50 for a column with a Field Size of 40 and on another it returns 100 for a column with a Field Size of 30 and 15 on a column with a Field Size of 16 but thanks for trying to help. I am using MaxLength is there something I may be doing wrong.

Comment: `MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey` fixed this same issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've run a quick test against a SQL database table - it looks like the MaxLength property isn't retrieved from the database and always has its value set as -1 unless specifically set by the user:

```
        string sql = "select top 10 * from [TestTable]";
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(data);

            foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                            col.ColumnName,
                            col.DataType.ToString(),
                            col.MaxLength
                        )
                    );
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: So in other words you mean to say there is absolutely no way I can retrieve the Field Size property from access

Comment: I really need a question to this answer because without being able to read the Max Length my whole program folds as the import will fail when there are too many characters

Comment: I fail to believe that this is so impossible because i can return the DataType with no problem at all

Comment: I've tried again using the OleDb providers and following @waqas's suggestion to include MissingSchemaAction settings. For a SQL Server database (I don't have MS-Access on this machine) the MaxLength is returned correctly. This could be an Access specific issue; the provider seems to be working fine.

Comment: Hmmm thanks I also see that because it returns total wrong values and not the field size